# R k-means clustering data

Tags: r, data-mining, k-means

in R, I have computed a k-means clustering as follows:

```
km = (mat2, centers=3)
```

where mat2 is a matrix of column vectors obtained by combining elements of a set of time series. There are 31 rows

Now that I have my k-means object how can I look at the data associated with a particular point? For example, supposed I clicked on a dot in that belongs to one of the partitions. How can I view this data? Of course what I mean is how to programmatically obtain this data.

Comment: You need to add more details; it's impossible to follow what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that you call `kmeans` as this:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame( row.names = paste0( "obs", 1:100 ), 
                         V1 = rnorm(100),
                         V2 = rnorm(100),
                         V3 = rnorm(100) )
km <- kmeans( df, centers = 3 )
```

If you are unfamiliar with a new function, it's always a good idea to inspect the resulting object using `str()`:

```
> str(km)
List of 7
 $ cluster     : Named int [1:100] 1 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:100] "obs1" "obs2" "obs3" "obs4" ...
 $ centers     : num [1:3, 1:3] 0.65604 -1.09689 0.56428 0.11162 0.00549 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "V1" "V2" "V3"
 $ totss       : num 291
 $ withinss    : num [1:3] 43.7 65.7 51.3
 $ tot.withinss: num 161
 $ betweenss   : num 130
 $ size        : int [1:3] 36 34 30
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "kmeans"
```

As I understood from your question, you are looking for `km$cluster`, which tells you which observation of your data has been assigned to which cluster. The cluster centers can accordingly be investigated by `km$centers`.

If you now want to know which observations has been clustered to the third cluster with the center `km$centers[3,]`, you can subset your `data.frame` (or `matrix`) by

```
> rownames(df[ km$cluster == 3, ])
 [1] "obs3"  "obs4"  "obs12" "obs15" "obs16" "obs21" "obs25" "obs27" "obs32" "obs42" "obs43" "obs46" "obs48" "obs54" "obs55" "obs58" "obs61" "obs62" "obs63" "obs66" "obs67" "obs73" "obs76"
[24] "obs77" "obs81" "obs84" "obs86" "obs87" "obs90" "obs94"
```